# Prevent user from replying to email

Tags: laravel

I am sending an email through laravel, which is working fine . What i want to do is prevent that user from replying to the sent email.Is there any no-reply working for email in laravel 6?

Comment: You can't prevent people from replying to emails. You can just use no-reply@ as your sender, to visualize that people shouldn't respond to it; but you can't prevent the attempt.

Comment: Are you sending/receiving emails within your application, or sending them out to an email service provider? If they are internal, then you could do something with logic to hide the `reply` button. If they are external then you can't.